# How do I change inputshape, include_top=False and freeze from a custom model tensorflow keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, object-detection

I have a custom model saved as model.h5. I want to use this pretrained model for transfer learning. I then need to change the input shape to (224,224,3), not include the top layer before i freeze it. How is the syntax for this? I know how to do it with a model from the library ex:

```
base_model = keras.applications.VGG16(
    weights='imagenet',  # Load weights pre-trained on ImageNet.
    input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
    include_top=False)
```

I want something like this:

```
from keras.models import load_model

base_model = load_model('model.h5', input_shape=(224,224,3), include_top=False)
base_model.trainable = False
```

Comment: You have to do it manually creating a submodel... what is for you the top / what layer are part of the top?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani Do you have an example for the syntax creating a submodel. And what do you mean by what is for me the top layer. Im using YOLOv3 Cross-Dataset and the weights and config in [this](https://github.com/cansik/yolo-hand-detection) github